# The contains of model hide when keyboard show in Ionic 2

Tags: html, model-view-controller, ionic2

I have small problem in my model. You can see the original design of my modal as shown in the image

[image]

But when I click on input. The model shows that contains of back page.

[image]

> note: this problem happens only when I used my app on real device ( android ) but there is no problem when I check it on PC

this is my html code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="{{this.appService.appColor}}">
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="viewCtrl.dismiss()">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Change Password
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
     <ion-list> 
        <ion-item style="background-color:#EAECEE">
           <label>Account Password</label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
           <ion-label style="width:45%; display: inline-block;">Old Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input required placeholder="******************" type="password" [(ngModel)]="opassword"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <!--<hr style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">-->

        <ion-item>
           <ion-label style="width:45%; display: inline-block;">New Password</ion-label>
           <ion-input required placeholder="******************" type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" (ionChange)="checkPass1Function(password,cpassword)"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
       <ion-item *ngIf="!checkPassword1 && checkPassword1!=null">
           <p style="color:red; white-space: pre-line; text-align: justify;">Password must contains at least 8 characters</p>
       </ion-item>

       <!--<hr style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">-->

       <ion-item>
           <ion-label style="width:45%; display: inline-block;">Re-Password</ion-label>
           <ion-input required placeholder="******************" type="password" [(ngModel)]="cpassword" (ionChange)="checkPass2Function(password, cpassword)"></ion-input>
       </ion-item>
       <ion-item *ngIf="!checkPassword2 && checkPassword2!=null">
            <p style="color:red; white-space: pre-line; text-align: justify;">Password does not match</p>
       </ion-item>
    </ion list>
    <hr style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <div padding-bottom>
        <button ion-button class="medium" (click)="save(opassword, password, cpassword)" full color="secondary" [disabled]="!opassword || !checkPassword1 || !checkPassword2">Save Changes</button>
    </div>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from my device that need update. Also, I checked 2 other devices and there is no problems